# If a report is released the morning of a seminar occurring later in the day, is the seminar likely to affect the price?

Tags: stocks

Do such seminars typically include new information, including information not in the morning's report? For instance, will the Orchard Therapeutics presentation later today likely do this?

Comment: What exactly is "seminar"?

Comment: He's probably referring to a healthcare conference where many pharma (and related) companies present.

Answer (score 1):

Any news has the potential to affect share price.  However, since this morning's report announced the positive clinical results and this afternoon's seminar is about reviewing the scientific data, I'd guess that the seminar won't affect price much unless some startling new information is released.  And given that the clinical results were for 8 patients, this might be a yawner.